# what will happen if overriding a class in my module used by another module

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I'm working on a module and I need a block file to be overridden in order to add new functionality. I know how to override *blocks*, *model* and *controllers* but I want to know that what will happen if the class I'd extended was being used by another module class?

**The above scenario is as follows:**
In my module **config.xml** I'd overridden a block file as:

```
<blocks>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <cart_shipping>Company_Module_Block_Cart_Shipping</cart_shipping>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

and override a method `getEstimateRates()`

but there's another module whose block file extends `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping`. My question is -

> "Will that class be able to see the changes made in the overridden class in my module?"

*OR*

> "Do I have to override the other modules block file?"

Comment: This could be helpful `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884838/how-to-override-community-block-module-with-php-file-in-magento/23885156#23885156`

Comment: that's one of the reasons you shouldn't override but use events instead

Answer (score 1):

One of yours or another extend block will not work. It can be fixed by extending yours or another block from one of them.

For example `Company_Module_Block_Cart_Shipping` is your block and `Other_Module_Block_Cart_Shipping` is other block.

If `Other_Module_Block_Cart_Shipping` is extended from core, you have to extend your `Company_Module_Block_Cart_Shipping` from `Other_Module_Block_Cart_Shipping`

Answer (score 0):

Magento makes a config.xml tree of all the config.xml of enabled modules.

Mage_All.xml is loaded first,
then all
Mage.*.xml
and preceding it your custom module .xml as per alphabetic sequence.

The sequence can be changed if you have given a depends tag in etc/modules/module definition xml.

Hope this clears your doubt.